# Printing API data (JSON) on page in NodeJS weather app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm creating a weather app using NodeJS.
I can get json formated data from the weather site API. But I don't understand how I can send it to the app.

here is my code:

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer (function (request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.end();
}).listen(3000);

var getUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=1111111111';

http.get(getUrl, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var response = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", response.coord.lon);
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to transform your example into working code would be to put the `response.end()` call inside your "getUrl"'s "onEnd" block:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer (function (request, response){

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    var getUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=1111111111';

    http.get(getUrl, function(res){

        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){

            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log("Got a response: ", data.coord.lon);

            response.end(JSON.stringify(data)); // ENDING/SENDING RESPONSE AFTER FETCHING URL IS DONE

        });
    }).on('error', function(e){
          console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

The main issue here being that the `createServer` callback will fire every time someone tries to access your webpage, and your "getUrl" logic is outside of that, thus wouldn't run on every request. Now that it's inside the server callback, it will. If you intend to add more functionality to this code, consider abstracting this "getUrl" functionality, but still call it from within the server callback.

Comment: Thanks! But your code throws an error on 'response.end(data)': TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer

Comment: Sorry about that, you just have to convert the "data" into a string with "JSON.stringify", updated the post to include that. However, if you don't need to do something with the data or console.log it, you could just pass the "body" variable (which is a string), directly to "response.end(body)".

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way you can do it without creating a server.

```
var http = require('http');
var getUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=1111111111';

var request = http.get(getUrl, function(response) {
    var jsonData = '';
    response.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    jsonData += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
       console.log(jsonData);
    });
});
request.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to createServer. because i plan to generate content on serverside. Btw i get JSON from API easily but cant paste it into my html template.